# adding a logo to the default login page FBA Authentication

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

Just wanting to know how to add a company logo to the default FBA authentication form.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom login page.The default login page of FBA in SharePoint 2010 is very simple. It only provides a Login control with the user name, password and remember me option.

follow the instruction below to create a custom login page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Comment: thanks for taking time to reply. We are very new to SharePoint 2013. The coding behind the scenes is something im not familiar with. im find on the user front edit, web parts etc. ive looked through these guides but it still doesn't make sense. I just cant see "code" to put in to point to a logo.png - am I thinking this is simple? and that actually putting a logo in is more work than I thought

Comment: The deafult login page is located here: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN\default.aspx. You can modify that in Visual Studio. I know you said that you didn't want to create a new one but you could make a copy of the deafult one, add that to a new project and make your changes to the copy. That way you will preserve the default login page if you need to revert back.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793696/custom-login-page-in-sharepoint-2013-with-fba-autentication

Comment: yeah I have made a few copies of this file. but I still don't see how to add my company logo in so it shows on the login page. its just the default login is very basic and dull

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the existing one, however you can create a custom FBA login page and do whatever styling you want.  There is a good blog post on MSDN about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/08/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-fba-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx